# Wordpress - How to get the most viewed posts?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, templates

How can I display my most viewed posts on a single page ?

For this moment, i've create a new template page (content-most-viewed.php) wich is called by get_template_part();

On Internet, i've read that query_posts could solve my problem, but it seems to fail.

This is my template :

```
<?php query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC');
//query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=10&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');?>
<div class="post">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="heading">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <?php the_content();?>
            <div class="link-holder"><a href="/index.php">Retour</a></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Not Found</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

But, I can only get recent posts, or "Not Found" (any resutls)

In advance, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress by itself does not keep track of the number a post is viewed there are pluging that do this: [WPP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/), [plugin repos](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=popular&sort=)
These plugins will have build in functions to do this.

**side note**
don't use `query_posts` its bad for preformance. use [`WP_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in stead. reasons why it is bad: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/10911, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/10911

Comment: Wordpress Popular Posts && WP_query didn't seems to help me :/

    $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&order_by=comments');

I get 2 posts, but 2 last posts, not 2 most commented posts ...

Comment: what about `order_by=comment_count` in the argument string?